# A file not found in spring boot project

Tags: spring-boot, filepath, filenotfoundexception

I meet a problem when I tried to write the json data to static file in my spring boot project. It occurs that the fileNotFound though I ensure that I have the file. The absolute path is just ok. [Here is my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aV1dT.png)

I write the path: /data/user.json 
How should I change the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding resource configuration like this,

```
@Configuration
public class WebViewConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers( ResourceHandlerRegistry registry )
    {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations("file:" "/path/to/file");


    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I write the config file like this: registry.addResourceHandler("/data/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/data/");   But it turns out error, how should I rewrite the path?

Comment: When you bundle your programme either WAR or JAR, resources files are places in different dir structure. Ex: When I bundle into Jar. Resources are bundled into classpath:/META-INF/resources/. So you can check for the exact path of the file after bundled and give the same. To check that, just extract the jar file and check for the file and its path

Answer (score 0):

This works for me to load a file from src/main/resources/documents

```
Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:documents/" + "file.txt");
```